# Is it possible to create a drop down list in html with a large amount of data?

Tags: html

Is it possible to create a drop down list in html with a large amount of data without using

```
<option>Something</option>
```

for each content.

For example, I want to make a drop down list with numbers 1-100. Is it required to define each one by one?

Comment: If you don't want to manually write out 100 options, you should generate the html programatically.

Answer (score 2):

Yes I tried the same after reading your question and it is possible to create a drop down list in html with a large amount of data:
I tried using Jquery because according to me it was simple to write and understand.
in your html you just need to write  tag with id.

```
<html>
<select id="select"> 

</select>
</html>​
```

Now in your Javascript(Do not forget to import jquery) you have to just write:

```
$(document).ready(function() {   
 for(i=1;i<=100;i++)
{
$("#select").append("<option>"+i+"</option>");
}    
});
```

In this way you can make drop down list of 1 to 100 in easier way.Hope this helps you :)

Comment: Some significant performance improvements could be made here. First you should avoid querying the DOM each time (i.e. store the result of $("#select") in a variable) and you should only do a single insert into the live DOM (to avoid browser re-rendering parts of the page as much as possible). The best way to do this is to create the collection in memory and then append all that right at the end (by having only a single insert you also get around the multiple queries issue)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Actually I am new to Jquery but can you elaborate more on how can I store the collection in the memory? Where should I define the same. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @user1389626 - [This post](http://24ways.org/2011/your-jquery-now-with-less-suck) has some good explanations of the optimizations that Wicky is talking about. Look specifically at the "Caching" and "DOM Manipulation" sections.

Comment: The article that Rusty linked to is an excellent resource, check that out. Also, good on you for joining stack overflow and helping others out :)

Comment: @WickyNilliams thanks a lot for giving good suggestion I will be looking forward for such suggestions always :)

Answer (score 1):

I would consider creating the markup server side (e.g. using PHP) or with JavasScript/jQuery.

Here's a jQuery example:

```
var options = [];
for (var n = 1; n <= 100; n++){
    options.push('<option value="' + n + '">' + n + '</option>');      
}
$('<select/>', {
  'id': 'my-select',
  'name': 'my-select',
  html: options.join('')
}).appendTo('body');
```

And a Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/XffwR/1/

Of course you may not want to go that route, in which case yes you would need to add HTML markup for each option manually, as John Conde says.

Comment: Global variables `n` and `options` detected.

Answer (score 1):

**You are not obliged to place your data in `<select><option>...` if you want to create a drop-down** interface component. The `<select>` is a standard, default and definitely a preferred way to do so. But you can imitate its behavior with other tags available.

Now, I see you want to put in lots of data and probably you don't want to do it by hand. HTML doesn't have markup structures that allow for automated content generation, so **yes, you have to define all those options in drop-down list yourself**. And every separate option has to be inside its own tag.

Now, that would be a tedious task, right? Never fear! Programming languages to the rescue. It is possible can create those tags automatically based on some data, be it predefined, generated in accordance to some parameters, or just random.

I'm not sure why everyone assumed that the question is about creating `<option>` tags in jQuery... there are many other options available.

1. **Server-side generation**: if you are using PHP, Python, or any other language on the server, you can build your `<select>` structure on the server, insert it into the html and present it to the user. If your data is static - you have a benefit of caching which reduces load on the server and on the network.
2. **Client-side generation**: you can use JavaScript to create those options as the page is being loaded (or on user request). Of course if you want to use some JavaScript framework that facilitates the process - you can use jQuery, Prototype, Zepto... whatever you wish to include with your page.

I'm not showing any code here because there's not much information in the question. For example, do you want to build your drop-down out of some predefined data. If yes - where and in which form do you think it will be stored? Will it be static or dynamic? Etc. etc. etc.

If you update your question with more details, then we can update our answers with more information. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you must define each one in it's own `<option>` tag.